# Is it correct for $\int {x^x}\, dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, error-function, power-towers

Recently, I was working with power towers. I was interested in $x^x$; it is easy to know its derivative, but I wanted to find its integral. Here's what I found. Please let me know if it is right or wrong.
We have $$x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$$

Now, $e^{x \ln x}$ is same as writing $ e^{\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)^2}$.
We know that,
\begin{align}\int e^{x^2} \,dx &= \frac {\sqrt\pi}{2} \operatorname{erfi}(x) +c\\[5pt]
\implies \int e^{\sqrt {(x \ln x)}^2}\, dx &= \frac {\frac {\sqrt\pi}{2}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{\frac {d\left(\sqrt{x \ln x}\right)}{dx}} +c
\end{align}
Comparing, we get,$$\int {x^x}\, dx = \frac {\frac {\sqrt\pi}{2}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{\frac {d\left(\sqrt{x \ln x}\right)}{dx}}+c $$
Simplifying, we get$$\int {x^x}\, dx = \frac {\sqrt{\pi x \ln x} \cdot \operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x \ln x}\right)}{1+\ln x} + c$$

Please help me know if it is correct/incorrect. Also, if correct, please tell me how to evaluate it by taking upper & lower limits.
 Thanks !

Comment: for $0<x<1$ you have $\ln(x)<0$ and hence there is a problem with your root.

Comment: $x=(\sqrt{x})^2$; would you claim that $\int e^x\,dx$ involves $\operatorname{erfi}\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: perhaps...everything is in front of you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that $$\int e^{\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)^2}\, dx = \frac {\frac {\sqrt\pi}{2}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{\frac {d\left(\sqrt{x \ln x}\right)}{dx}} +c$$ is not true.  If we differentiate the right-hand side, we should obtain $e^{\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)^2}$, but we don't.  Instead, we get $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{2\sqrt{x\ln x}} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi x\ln x}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{x\left(\ln x + 1\right)^2} + x^x,
$$ see [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+sqrt%28pi%29*sqrt%28xln%28x%29%29*+erfi%28sqrt%28xln%28x%29%29%29%2F%28ln%28x%29+%2B+1%29).  The issue is that there is no substitution that gives the change of variables $$\int e^{\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)^2}\, dx \longrightarrow \int e^{x^{2}}\,dx.$$  We would need try to use the substitution
\begin{align}
u &= \sqrt{x\ln x}\\
du &= \frac{\ln x + 1}{2\sqrt{x\ln x}}\,dx
\end{align}
which will not give us the intended transformation.

Comment: yes, i got it, thank u vry much

Answer (score 4):

We know that if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $F\big(g(x)\big)$ is an antiderivative of $f\big(g(x)\big)g'(x)$. In your question, you seem to *think* that $f\big(g(x)\big)$ has an antiderivative $F\big(g(x)\big)/g'(x)$. But $$\Big(F\big(g(x)\big)/g'(x)\Big)'=f\big(g(x)\big)\underbrace{{}-F\big(g(x)\big)g''(x)/g'^2(x)}_{\text{your mistake}}.$$

Comment: ya...i got it; thanks for helping me

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in this step

\begin{align}\int e^{x^2} \,dx &= \frac {\sqrt\pi}{2} \operatorname{erfi}(x) +c\\[5pt]
\implies \int e^{\sqrt {(x \ln x)}^2}\, dx &= \frac {\frac {\sqrt\pi}{2}\operatorname{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x\ln x}\right)}{\frac {d\left(\sqrt{x \ln x}\right)}{dx}} +c
\end{align}

You can't just substitute $x$ by $\sqrt{x \ln x}$ in the integral.

Comment: but i used chain rule, right?

Comment: You tried, but you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: what is correct way then... pls help...

Comment: For clarity, let's use another variable. In $\int e^{t^2}\,dt$ take $t =\sqrt{x \log x}$, then   $$\int e^{t^2}\,dt = \int e^{(\sqrt{x \log x})^2}\,d(\sqrt{x \log x}) = \int e^{x \log x} \frac{\log (x)+1}{2 \sqrt{x \log (x)}} \,dx$$ So you don't get the integral you are trying to calculate.

Comment: oh yes...i messed up there, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The argument of Kevin is right. Presently this integral cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of available standard functions (including elementary and special functions defined and standardized in the past).

But new special functions can be defined and standardized in the futur. See this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function
$$\int_0^x t^{\alpha\,t} dt=\text{Sphd}(\alpha\:;\:x)$$
Thus
$$\int x^{x} dx=\text{Sphd}(1;x)+\text{constant}$$
About the common use of special functions a paper for the general public : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: Did you mean $t$ instead of $e$ in the integrals?

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = x^x$ cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions.

There is no simple answer to your question, unless you are willing to consider a series approximation, obtained by expanding the exponential as a series:

$$\int{x^xdx} = \int{e^{\ln x^x}dx} = \int{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k\ln^k x}{k!}}dx$$

Comment: *...in terms of elementary functions.* - but $\color{DarkBlue}{\operatorname{erfi}}$ is *not* elementary.

Comment: @metamorphy I know this, that doesn't negate anything I've written above.

Comment: pls someone let me know what is derivative of erfi(x)... i don't know it...sry

Comment: ya, i did it..... but when we take x ln(x), we get same ans as i got above....

Answer (score 1):

What you write is wrong. But anyhow, just plot the integral function
$$
F(t)=\log\left(\int_0^t x^x dx\right), \quad t\geq 0, 
$$ and you can see all the properties you are interested in. After that, you can focus on proving just those properties of $F$ you see in the graph and you are interested in. Soon, you will realize that you know about $F$ the same you know about $e^t$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the graphs, are you plotting $\ln F(t)$?

Comment: Yes yes...i understood where i messed....thanku for helping

Comment: Yes I forgot the log, sorry :-) I fixed.